# Animating buttons placed in a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to give buttons a "press down" animation upon mouse hover and another, smaller press down animation when the user clicks. I currently have the animation working but when the mouse hovers over one button, all buttons are animated. I tried targeting each button individually but didn't have any luck.

I would also like to give each button a set width and height so that they are all the same size. I've tried giving a set width and messed around with the display CSS element but haven't had any success. I can't get the ISSUU embed to show up either, so if there are any suggestions or advice on this as well that would be awesome (Pre-Edit: Looks like it shows up in the JSFiddle, albeit incorrectly, as well as the buttons. Here is what it looks like [on my browser](https://i.gyazo.com/55475054e3863b07c49109cf26ca2bef.png)).

My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ewrcxrrp/

HTML:

```
<div id="cookbook">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <h1>Order the lemonade cookbook</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="six columns">
            <div data-configid="0/5714789" class="issuuembed"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//e.issuu.com/embed.js" async="true"></script> 
      </div>
      <div class="six columns">
        <p>"As a chef, I have a very high bar that has to be met for me to enjoy other people’s food. Alan Jackson’s lemonade has more than exceeded that bar."</p>
        <p1>- MICHAEL CHIARELLO, OWNER OF THE CRITICALLY ACCLAIMED BOTTEGA</p1>
        <h2>get your copy:</h2>
  
          <button type="submit" class="button-primary">Amazon</button>
          <button type="submit" class="button-primary">Barnes &amp; Noble</button>
          <button type="submit" class="button-primary">Indie Bound</button>
          <button type="submit" class="button-primary">Powell's Books</button>
          <button type="submit" class="button-primary">Books-a-Million</button>
          <button type="submit" class="button-primary">Overstock</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cookbook{
  background-image: url(http://i.lmnd3.com/images/LemonadeBkg_Broc.jpg);
  position: float;
  min-height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}
#cookbook .issuuembed {
    width: 525px;
    height: 340px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#cookbook h1{
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

#cookbook p{
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
#cookbook p1{
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-weight: 400;
}

#cookbook h2{
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cookbook button{

  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #E4572E;
  border-color: #E4572E;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 0px 0px #888888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #888888;
  box-shadow:         0px 2px 0px 0px #888888;
}

#cookbook button:hover{
  margin-top: 1px;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px .5px 0px 0px #888888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px .5px 0px 0px #888888;
  box-shadow:         0px .5px 0px 0px #888888;
}

#cookbook button:active{
  margin-top: 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 0px 0px #888888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #888888;
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 0px 0px #888888;
}
```

Any help or guidance is really appreciated!

All the best -

Comment: All of the buttons move because you're changing the size of one of them on hover and their positions are based on their size, so the browser has to move them all.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what Mohamed just wrote, there is one more problem with CSS - when hover over button happens, you add top margin 1px to button, as a result all buttons are forced 1px down and appears to be animated. Change button hover CSS to this

```
#cookbook button:hover {
   margin-top: 1px;
   margin-bottom: 9px;
   -moz-box-shadow:    0px .5px 0px 0px #888888;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px .5px 0px 0px #888888;
   box-shadow:         0px .5px 0px 0px #888888;
}
```

Add `margin-bottom: 9px;` to compensate for 1px top margin on hovered button.

Also add a similar `margin-bottom: 8px;` to the :active state, to keep all the following buttons in from shifting when you click on one:

```
#cookbook button:active {
   margin-top: 2px;
   margin-bottom: 8px;
   -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 0px 0px #888888;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #888888;
   box-shadow:         0px 0px 0px 0px #888888;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying and can see what is causing the unwanted animating now, but unfortunately this solution isn't working for me. I'll keep messing around with it and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: Could you be more specific, what is still wrong? Because I applied fix I mentioned above to the fiddle you posted, and buttons seems working as they suppose to. What's still not working correctly for you?

Comment: I was still having the issue of other buttons below the one I was hovering over being animated when they weren't supposed to. I stumbled upon the translate element in the transform css property though, and got everything working correctly. :) Thanks for the help! [Transform](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)

Answer (score 0):

Thats happening because you are using the wrong class first of all. Are you using bootstrap as part of your css?.

2. In your CSS, you used hashtags instead of a dot (.) which is used to classify a css tag and can be triggered with "class". If you want to use a hashtag, you need to use:

   id="cookbook button" instead of class="button-primary" on the button tag.

That is your only problem. You did not declare the css to the html document properly. If you change the hashtags to a dot (.cookbook button), then you can just add "cookbook button" to the css class declared on the HTML next to "button-primary" without any problems.

Comment: In a nutshell, change class="button-primary" to id="cookbook button" since you used hashtags instead of a Dot (.) in the css file. 
Then your "Mouse Hover" & "Active" should also work

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I'm using the skeleton CSS framework, which uses button-primary to create buttons. The skeleton CSS that I use is in the JSFiddle I posted.

Comment: Even with the button-primary class tag, you can still add a "id" tag. The id tag should equal the name of the css element you put in your css file --> id="cookbook button" .